# Websockets persistant connection

Tags: c#, websocket, network-programming, long-polling, polling

Since the connection is persistent, i understand a lot of network congestion is prevented in setting up the new connection, in cases like periodic polling of hundreds of servers.
I have a simple question. Does not it put load on the both server and client to keep the connection persistent for a long time ? Is the gain made lost??

Answer (score 1):

A TCP (and hence WebSocket) connection established to a server, but not sending or receiving (sitting idle), does consume memory on the server, but no CPU cycles.

To keep the TCP connection alive (and also "responsive") on certain network environment like mobile *may* require periodic sending/receiving of small amounts of data. E.g. WebSocket has built-in ping/pong (non app data) messages for that. Doing so then will consume some CPU cycles, but not a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Persistent connections are a tradoff.

Yes, they require the server to store the state associated with each connection, they require maintenance (such as keep-alive packets or websocket pings), and they require monitoring (to detect state changes or arriving information). So you spend some memory and CPU resources per connection.

**BUT** they save a lot of time, and often resources, on connection re-initializations; once established, they allow both parties to send and receive information as opposed to non-persistent client-server systems like classic HTTP.

So it really depends on the system you're building. If your system has millions of users that need connectivity to the server only once in a while, then the benefit of keeping these connections open is probably not worth the extra resources. But if you're designing something like a chat server for hundred people, then the additional responsiveness is probably worth it.